# Want to solve the error cause while install openpifpaf while install in command prompt for opencv

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, python-wheel, openpifpaf

error caused while installing openpifpaf in command prompt for a human detection and i also installed all requirements but it cause error in build wheels for openpifpaf

```
Error:
 C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8sns8i89\overlay\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:358: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
        warnings.warn(f'Error checking compiler version for {compiler}: {error}')
      building 'openpifpaf._cpp' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for openpifpaf
Failed to build openpifpaf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for openpifpaf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I try to install openpifpaf but it cause error and i want it open opencv webcam and access human activity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 0):

Install using `Conda` or `Poetry` issues will be handled by them itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it clears the error

Comment: Glad to know, please upvote the answer and mark it as answer